# Determine delimiter for a CSV/Excel file based on Operating System

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, user-agent, navigator

I have a React application where I'm giving options to download some data either as a CSV or Excel. It works fine in Windows when I use a comma as a delimiter (to separate cells in a row). But it does not work in Mac.
If I use semi-colon as a delimiter, it works fine in Mac, but merges all cells together in Windows.

I think the solution is to choose the delimiter depending on the operating system of the user. But I'm not sure what's the recommended way to detect operating system. Or even better, if there's a certain feature that we can detect because most of the documentation suggests against detecting OS based on properties like `window.navigator.platform` or `window.navigator.userAgent`.

Thanks